# The combination of $p_i(x) =\prod_{i \not= j} (x-\lambda_j)$ forms the basis for the set of polynomials with degree $\le n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Show that the combination of $p_i(x) =\prod_{i \not= j} (x-\lambda_j)$ forms the basis for the set of polynomials with degree $\le n$.

$p_0(x) = (x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)…(x-\lambda_n)$

$p_1(x) = (x-\lambda_0)(x-\lambda_2)…(x-\lambda_n)$

…

$p_n(x) = (x-\lambda_0)(x-\lambda_1)…(x-\lambda_{n-1})$

If it is a basis then it generates the set of polynomial with degree $\le n$ and the elements are independent.

Showing independence:
$t_0p_0(x)+t_1p_1(x) + … + t_np_n(x) = 0$

The question is how?

Comment: Evaluate in $\lambda_i$ and you obtain $t_i=0$.

Comment: @Gae.S. You mean open the brackets?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $$\sum_{i=0}^n a_ip_i(x)\equiv 0\;\; (*)$$ we see that $\forall j \; p_i(\lambda_j)\ne 0\iff i=j$, so evaluating $(*)$ in $\lambda_j$ we have $a_jp_j(\lambda_j)=0\implies a_j=0$. As this is valid for all $js$ the polinomials are indipendent and they are $n+1$ that is the dimension of the space, so they generate!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $t_0p_0(x)+\ldots+t_n p_n(x)=0$, take $x=\lambda_i$ for all $i\in[\![0,n]\!]$ (calculate $p_i(\lambda_j)$). To show that it generates, if $q\in\mathbb{R}_n[X]$, to show that $q=\sum_{i=0}^n{t_i p_i}$ for some $(t_0,\ldots,t_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ you can show that $q(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n{t_i p_i(x)}$ for at least $n+1$ different values of $x$. Try with $t_i=q(\lambda_i)$.

Answer (score 2):

We have that 
$$p_j(\lambda_i)=0 \ \mbox{ if } \ i \neq j,$$
and 
$$ p_i(\lambda_i)\neq 0.$$
So if we take the linear combination $\sum_{j=0}^nt_jp_j(x)=0,$ then for all $i=0,\ldots,n$ we have that

$$t_ip_i(\lambda_i)= \sum_{j=0}^nt_jp_j(\lambda_i)=0.$$

From this it follows that $t_i=0$.